# Data presentation

Tags: asp.net

This is an off the wall question but I have always gotten great support here so maybe you can offer me some ideas.

I have a web app that is going to present data in a geographical fashion.  Some people have expressed a favorable impression of using a map which I have implemented while others want to find the data in a list type fashion.  Thing is - I don't wish to present it in a list since that infers some sort of sort order when there isn't any.  Are there any novel, impressive, different ways of presenting this data that might be considered an alternative to the maps that people would see and say 'oh that is cool'

Sorry for the vagueness  - but the idea is in development and well...

Comment: I am going to offer both views but want to have the 'other' view something more than a boring list that infers a sort order.

Comment: If values in the data have meaning, that is if you have data point closer to one location you can make the data point larger or smaller.  Similar to scatter plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some examples of [Maps](http://quince.infragistics.com/#/Search%24filter=M/ViewPattern%24pattern=Map&lang=en) and [Treemaps](http://quince.infragistics.com/#/Search%24filter=T/ViewPattern%24pattern=Treemap&lang=en) techniques on Quince. Maybe that would help you.